# Solving Diffusion Equation with Non-Homogeneous Mixed Conditions - Robin & Neumann

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I've been grappling with this problem for a while now and am at a loss. Here is the problem statement for a function $c(x,t)$ as defined by the following parabolic equation:

$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D_V \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$

$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}|_{x=0} + \beta_1(t) c|_{x=0} = g_1(t)$

$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}|_{x=L} = 0$

$c|_{t=0} = c_0, constant$

Here there is a non-homogeneous Robin condition and a homogeneous Neumann condition. Originally, I thought to homogenize the boundary conditions and proceed to use the method of Eigenfunction expansion to solve the problem, but I note that $\beta_1$ is a function of $t$. Are there any other alternatives I should explore?

---

Comment: You could still do that, if you can even find a function satisfying both BCs in the first place. Then you would have a time-dependent forcing, but that's OK if you can find the appropriate spacetime propagator.

Comment: @Ian Ok. Cool. I've been able to get a forcing function that solely a function of time, so I guess I will accept it. If you don't time, could you elaborate more on this concept of a spacetime propagator? I've using these methods blindly without proof up to this point.

Comment: The more colloquial term is "Green's function". The difficulty is that you need it to respect the boundary conditions. Once you have it and a function $f$ satisfying the boundary conditions, you can just rewrite the equation for the solution minus $f$ and then convolve the Green's function with the "effective forcing" that falls out of this subtraction of $f$. But again, finding the Green's function in the first place is generally not trivial.

Comment: @Ian I looked up Green's function and it's sorta goes over my head. Is the basic idea to always equate the linear operator with a dirac delta? Is this any different than finding the eigenfunctions of an operator?

Comment: I don't think you can represent this time dependent forcing as a superposition of spacetime eigenfunctions. I could be wrong. Anyway yes, the Green's function is given by equating the linear operator with a Dirac delta. In the context of a BVP, thenresponse depends on where the impulse was located, so the Green's function in your problem depends on 4 variables, and you integrate two of them out to get the solution. I am honestly not sure whether the Green'a function can be found analytically in this context.

Comment: @Ian I figured out the eigenfunctions of the problem and found that my eigenvalues, $\lambda_n$ are time-variant and should be the positive roots of $tan(\lambda_n L) = -\beta_1(t)/\sqrt(\lambda_n)$. At this point, I figured that I could find $\lambda_n$ by taking the power series expansion of $tan(\lambda_n L)$ and deal with a polynomial in $\lambda_n$. Not sure how to proceed further. The form could have also been $tan(\lambda_n^2 L) = -\beta_1(t)/\lambda_n$, depending on how defined my separation constant for the homogenous problem to find the eigenfunctions. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that helps if the eigenvalues are time-dependent, because it means there aren't actually separable eigenfunctions of the linear operator itself. Honestly I suspect that in practice you are stuck with numerics here.

Comment: @Ian In that case, upon homogenizing the BCs, would a finite Fourier Cosine Transform be acceptable? I've got even order derivative in the PDE in $x$. If so, I could be left with a IVP.

Comment: When you say homogenizing, do you mean converting them to be $c_x(0)=c_x(L)=0$? If not, then no, because the actual solution isn't a superposition of cosines.

Comment: @ Ian Converted the problem via: $c(x,t) = v(x,t) - \bar{c}(x,t)$, where $\bar{c}(x,t)$ allows the problem statement be converted to the following: 

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = D_V \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial \bar{c}}{\partial t} $,

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{x = 0} +\beta_1(t)c|_{x = 0} = 0 $,

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}|_{x = L} = 0$,

$v(x,0) = c_0 - \bar{c}(t=0)$,

Where $\bar{c}(x,t) = \frac{g_1(t)}{\beta_1(t)}$. Here I was thinking about either using Green's Function (which I'm new to) or Laplace Transform (which I don't know). What now?

Comment: So if you have a function $c_0(x,t)$ satisfying the BC, then you can write $c=c_0+c_1$ in which case you have $\partial_t c = \partial_t c_0 + \partial_t c_1 = D_V \partial_{xx} c = D_V \partial_{xx} c_0 + D_V \partial_{xx} c_1$. Thus $\partial_t c_1 = D_V \partial_{xx} c_1 + D_V \partial_{xx} c_0 - \partial_t c_0$. The BC for $c_1$ is now $\left. \partial_x c_1 + \beta_1 c_1 \right |_{x=0}=0$ and $\left. \partial_x c_1 \right |_{x=L}=0$.

Comment: But you still have a time-dependent BC which leaves you stuck. I don't think the Green's function for these BCs can be found explicitly. And I don't see how a temporal Laplace transform helps any, unless the Laplace transform of $\beta_1$ is *extremely* simple.

Comment: Ok. In that case, I'd try to take a complex Fourier Transform of my problem in the domain $x : [0,L]$, where I assume that everywhere else it is zero. This would force me to take a convolution of my robin boundary condition since $c_{x = 0}$ would be temporally variant and so is $\beta_1(t)$. Is it right to say that the Fourier Transform of a product of two functions is the same as their convolution? And would it be of any help in arriving to the solution?

Comment: @Ian, Thanks for your correspondence. I've learned a lot in the process of exploring this question. At present I've come to find that the conventional methods in PDE are insufficient to tackle this problems.